# RANDOM FILES to add records to textfile but instead of them being displayed on different lines they are being written on the same line

Tags: vb.net

that's how im opening the file:

```
FileOpen(1, TxtChosenFile.Text, OpenMode.Random, , , Len(ObjItem))
```

that's the structure:

```
Private ObjItem As New item
Private NewObjItem As New item

Structure item
    Dim id As Integer
    <VBFixedString(30)> Dim description As String
    Dim type As String
    Dim quantity As Integer
    Dim UnitPrice As Integer
End Structure
```

and that's the button enter code:

```
ObjItem.description = TxtDescription.Text
ObjItem.id = TxtItemNumber.Text
ObjItem.quantity = TxtQantity.Text
ObjItem.type = CmbType.Text
ObjItem.UnitPrice = TxtUnitPrice.Text

temp = ObjItem.id 
       & "," & 
       ObjItem.description
       & "," & 
       ObjItem.type
       & "," &
       ObjItem.quantity
       & "," & 
       ObjItem.UnitPrice

FilePutObject(1, temp, RecordNumber:=TxtItemNumber.Text
```

Comment: When you're concatenating the temp string, use Environment.NewLine instead of ",".

Comment: Thanks this worked but in the text file in the begining of each record im getting like an unrecognised language its like 2 rectangles at the beginning of each record